# Swiper js with Vaadin 10

Tags: css, vaadin, swiper.js, vaadin10

I have a problem with using swiper with Vaadin 10. When i tried simple slider with vaadin 10 and it works fine with

- Chrome(Succes)
- Opera(Succes)
- Mozilla(Failed)
- Edge(Failed)

Here is my sample code:

```
function slideIni(container) {
    var mySwiper = new Swiper(container, {
        // Optional parameters
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: true,
        effect: 'coverflow',
        speed: 1500,
        autoplay: {
            delay: 3000,
            disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        coverflowEffect: {
            rotate: 15,
            stretch: 0,
            depth: 100,
            modifier: 1,
            slideShadows: true,
        },
    });
};
```

When i use swiper with raw html its works fine. Any advice ?

[image: Fail]

Comment: Could you explain what the issue is that you are running into? Does your app otherwise work fine in Edge and FF except for the swipe plugin?

Comment: I need some slide show view into my project. And it's works all browsers except FF and Edge. My project is fine without swipe. And i don;t know what did i do wrong. Anyways app is good only swiper broke on FF and Edge

Comment: So do you see any errors in the dev console?  Is this third party webcomponent (i assume?) simply not supported for those browsers?

Comment: Nope, Don't see any error.